# iRobot Roomba compatible with ROS2 other than the Create?

Tags: ros2, irobot-create

I plan to buy an iRobot to test ROS2, but the Create 3 not available in my country, import tax and shipping cost may very high, also sometime custom will reject the import. But many other model from iRobot available like 627, I7, J7 ..., So what model compatible with ROS? Or I should by the Create 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The iRobot models 627, i7, and j7 are consumer-grade robotic vacuum cleaners and are not natively compatible with ROS. Do not expect the same level of programmability or integration capabilities as the Create 3.

The Create series is designed for robotic development and is compatible with ROS 2. Create 3 is actually the base for Turtlebot 4. My answer is that it should be Create 3 or a custom robot you make.

If getting it is hard, and there are no alternatives in your region, why don't you try making your own mobile robot? This will help you much more than just trying ROS 2. This [series](https://articulatedrobotics.xyz/mobile-robot-full-list/) is a good resource for that.

Comment: Thank you, I am trying to purchase Create 3 but it is for US only, I will try you suggestion.